# Combine 2 8 bit byte array positions to a single 16 bit integer

Tags: java, android

I have a byte array in which a value is stored as a 16bit unsigned integer.  This is spread across two positions in my byte array, `DataArray[11]` and `DataArray[12]`.  The documentation I have for the packet which contains the byte array tells me that the value I need to extract is packed least significant bit first.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around bitmasks and bit shifting, and I'm actually unclear if I need to use one or the other, or both.

This is what I have so far, but the results don't seem right:

```
int result =  (DataArray[11] << 8 | DataArray[12]) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: "the results don't seem right" doesn't tell us anything useful. Please give an example of sample input and output...

Comment: If DataArray type is byte, you may have trouble shift of 8 bit to the left!!!! cast array item to unsigned short before the shift.

Comment: @alexbuisson: There's no shift operator for byte anyway - it's going to be promoted to `int` automatically... and there's no `unsigned short` type in Java.

Comment: sorry if thought it was tagged as c++

Comment: Input is a val 0-65535.  The output I'm getting is only 3 digits, like 153, 157, 161, etc. I believe this is caused by the bitmask I have applied.  I'm not even sure I need it.  As I said I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.  I suppose I basically just need to concatenate 2 byte array positions and convert to an integer.  I'm not sure if it matters if it's unsigned and LSB first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to get a 16-bit integer, right? But you're masking it using `& 0xff` - which limits you to 8 bits. I suggest you mask *each byte* rather than the result:

```
int result = (DataArray[11] & 0xff) |
             ((DataArray[12] & 0xff) << 8);
```

I've included more parentheses here than are probably required, just for the sake of sanity and not needing to worry about precedence.

I've also swapped the ordering so that you're shifting `DataArray[12]` rather than `DataArray[11]`, as it's meant to be *least*-significant byte first.

Comment: The latter gives the wrong result if DataArray[12] is negative due to sign extension. Also, LSB first means you have to swap the array positions

Comment: @Joni: Ah, good point about the second form. Will delete that, and fix the ordering.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon Skeet, this seems to work very well.  Just so I understand correctly, the bitmask 0xFF makes sure I get only what I need from each array position, and the "<< 8" shifts the bits in the final 16 bit integer due to the LSB, is that correct?

Comment: @user2565357: The `& 0xff` effectively treats each byte as an *unsigned* value instead of signed. The `<< 8` shifts the most significant byte left by 8 bits.